# Why does the usermeta table contain html entities?

Tags: user-meta, core, htmlspecialchars-decode

As a plugin developer, I have been storing special characters like ampersand as is in MySQL tables, then converting them to html entities after retrieving them for display.

Now I discover that (for example) wp_insert_user() converts them to entities *before* storing them in the database.

Have I been doing this the wrong way round?  Should I convert before storing and then not convert when retrieving?

Has Wordpress Core adopted any convention for this?  What do other plugin developers do?

Comment: sanitise early, escape late, escape often